# Telegram contact addition problem

Tags: contacts, telegram

I'm trying to add a contact on Telegram, the specified number can be added through other phones, but not the same here:

> [image: contact]
> <sup>Screenshot (click to enlarge)</sup>
>
> [Name] is not on Telegram yet, would you like to invite them to join?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to add a Telegram contact, which **only work** if this user has a Telegram account.

It's not just like adding a contact to your phone.
You can add this number to your regular contact list, and search it (by the saved name) in Telegram. **If the user has a Telegram account - you'll see it**.

---

If you mean that in other phones you can add him as a *Telegram contact* directly, you might want to try and share the contact from one of the other phones with yourself:

- Open Telegram, find the contact, open its details and select share. Send it to your Telegram account. Don't use the contact attachment button, it works differently.

If that's the case, it's very weird. I really can't see any reason it would happen.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the user you're trying to add doesn't have a telegram account or go to settings app manager telegram clear the cache out only the cache then try again